# How to reset the results after you filtered a table

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to put a button (after the use of the filter feature) in the table to clean the search fields and return automatically to the table. How can I do it?

Now the code works like this:

First, you need to click the clear button, and then to return to the whole table you need to click the button "returns to the table".

Thanks and sorry for my English.

```js
function myFilterTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, xtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFilterTable()" placeholder="search " /><input type="reset" value="Clear" title="clear text" /></p>
</form>
<p><button onclick="myFilterTable()" title="click clean before returning to the table">return to the table</button></p>
<table id="myTable" bordercolor="dodgerblue" border="4" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">/</th>
            <th scope="col">wine</th>
            <th scope="col">beer</th>
            <th scope="col">water</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>table</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>city<span style="white-space:pre"> </span></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>house</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share a MCVE to give you furhter help. SO doesn't provide a coding service. Read this article to create a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Also specify what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks

Comment: You only have a table closing tag.

Comment: you're right, I fixed everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, avoid using the `type="reset"`, it works great with forms, but that's not the case.

Instead, use a `type="button"` and bind two actions:

- clear the input field
- invoke `myFilterTable()` again, so it will re-perform the filter on an empty string and will show all results

It's easier than it seems:

```js
function myFilterTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, xtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function resetSearch() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  input.value = '';
  myFilterTable();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFilterTable()" placeholder="search " /><input type="button" onclick="resetSearch()" value="Clear" title="clear text" /></p>
</form>
<p><button onclick="myFilterTable()" title="click clean before returning to the table">return to the table</button></p>
<table id="myTable" bordercolor="dodgerblue" border="4" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">/</th>
            <th scope="col">wine</th>
            <th scope="col">beer</th>
            <th scope="col">water</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>table</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>city<span style="white-space:pre"> </span></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>house</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a paramter to your function as boolean. Set it to true on clear button click.

I also recommend to use javascript event binding over inline.

```js
function myFilterTable(clear) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, xtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = clear ? "" : input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFilterTable(false)" placeholder="search " /><input onclick="myFilterTable(true)" type="reset" value="Clear" title="clear text" /></p>
</form>
<table id="myTable" bordercolor="dodgerblue" border="4" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">/</th>
            <th scope="col">wine</th>
            <th scope="col">beer</th>
            <th scope="col">water</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>table</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>city<span style="white-space:pre"> </span></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>house</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```